# Remove H1 / title / Underscore - without CSS

Tags: functions, title, underscore

I have tried searching, and tried a few options, but I'm not able to remove the H1 / title / Underscore for specific pages.

I don't want use CSS. I would like to remove it via `functions.php` or in `content.php`.

I'm not good in PHP, so the Codex didn't help me too much.

I need something like this:

```
if > page slugs / IDs > do not display H1/ title
```

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: You can remove the h1 from any template that has it like index or page or single php, but why would you want to? You're going to seriously hurt your SEO without an h1 title in there. I suggest creating an absolute position that takes the <h1> off the page but not out of the document.

Comment: I need add own H1.

Comment: Your problem can be soved by using `is_page()` function as suggested by `Devender Narwal`. Have you tried with that function? Have you understood how you can use this function in your page.php? Please tell your progress from posting question here to till now since you got two answer, How much they helpful to you and what problem you have left with you.

Comment: Well, I have tried a lot of codes from Google, but nothing worked. As I said Im not good (still learning) in php, so Im asking for exact help. I developed one code, that I use in function.php for calling JS for specific pages. But I dont know how finish it for H1 problem:  `if ( is_page('xxxx', 'xxxx') ) {`

Comment: I highly recommend you not remove H1's from your templates. It's unsemantic and bad for your SEO.

Comment: If you getting trouble in removing `h1` on certain pages using is_page() function then show some code that contains `h1`. And one more thing, in your previous comment I am assuming the code that you typed (`if ( is_page('xxxx', 'xxxx') )`) is not working in case if `h1`. Then try to use this code like this instead : `if ( is_page('xxxx') || is_page('xxxx'))`. That might work!

Comment: Here is code from template content-page.php `<header class="entry-header">
  <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
 </header><!-- .entry-header -->` And html output: `<header class="entry-header">
  <h1 class="entry-title">Index</h1> </header><!-- .entry-header -->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this is to create a separate page template that lacks the H1 code, and then manually select that template (in the Page Attributes box on the page editor screen) for each desired page.

Comment: Hello @RobSterling - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Please refrain from asking questions in answers - such information is typically best discussed in comments on the original question (though I understand that you may not be able to post comments quite yet).

Comment: OK, removed the question I had posted after answering his question broadly.

Comment: It is clever idea Rob! But I think, code will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has the predefined function `is_page()`, which looks like this:

```
is_page( int|string|array $page = '' )
```

If the `$page` parameter is specified, this function will additionally check if the query is for one of the pages specified.

It returns `true` or `false`, depending on whether the query is for an existing single page.

You can find more details [in the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/).

Comment: Hi Devender, welcome to WPSE. While this might answer part of the question, it doesn't answer the whole question - specifically, how to not actually display the title. Are you able to edit your answer to expand?

Comment: Hi Time,  Now it is looking professionally and now onwards i will keep in mind that answer should be in that way thank you

Comment: One plus vote for more specific answer .-) thx